# Is there a way to remove a widget from the tree after button press?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter newbie here. I'm trying to make a simple to-do list that I'm using to build up my skills. The idea is there is a to-do list that you can move the properties up and down and once you complete a task you check it off and it should display a checkmark and maybe eventually play an animation and remove it. For now, I'm stuck on just removing it, I had a few implementation ideas, but a lot of them will require me to restart my code. Is there a way to make it so that once I am done with a specific widget I can delete it or replace it with another, noting the fact that these widgets are in a list? code for reference:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var checkboxes = [
    Checkboxstate(title: "test"),
    Checkboxstate(title: "test2"),
    Checkboxstate(title: "test3"),
    Checkboxstate(title: "tes4t"),
  ];
  bool value = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("To-Do"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ReorderableListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
            setState(() {
              if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                newIndex -= 1;
              }
              var item = checkboxes.removeAt(oldIndex);
              checkboxes.insert(newIndex, item);
            });
          },
          children: [
            ...checkboxes.map(buildBox).toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Card buildBox(Checkboxstate checkbox) {
    return Card(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(checkbox.title),
        key: UniqueKey(),
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        value: checkbox.value,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            checkboxes.removeAt();
            checkbox.value = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Checkboxstate {
  String title;
  bool value;
  Checkboxstate({this.title, this.value = false});
}
```

EDIT:
As suggested by Prabhanshu I followed his steps and instead used the item builder; however, there is a new issue: the reorderablelistview now doesn't work. My idea was that the reason was that the index was different for the reorderable list than the checkbox widget I create, but I am still unable to find a solution.

new code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var checkboxes = [
    Checkboxstate(title: "test"),
    Checkboxstate(title: "test2"),
    Checkboxstate(title: "test3"),
    Checkboxstate(title: "tes4t"),
  ];
  bool value = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("To-Do"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ReorderableListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
            setState(() {
              if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                newIndex -= 1;
              }
              var item = checkboxes.removeAt(oldIndex);
              checkboxes.insert(newIndex, item);
            });
          },
          itemCount: checkboxes.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Checkboxstate box = checkboxes.elementAt(index);
            return buildBox(box, index);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Card buildBox(Checkboxstate checkbox, int index) {
    return Card(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(checkbox.title),
        key: UniqueKey(),
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        value: checkbox.value,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            checkbox.value = value;
            checkboxes.removeAt(index);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Checkboxstate {
  String title;
  bool value;
  Checkboxstate({this.title, this.value = false});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***If drag to dismiss is an option:***

What you're looking for here is the `Dismissible` Widget, which as the docs describe is a widget that can be dismissed by dragging in the indicated direction.

Check out the [flutter cookbook tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible) for a detailed explanation
on how to use this widget.

Comment: I thought so too, but the dismissable only works by sliding, I want to make it so that it dismisses on the checkbox press.

Comment: Let me see how dismissable is implemented and get back to you

Comment: Okay so, you should not have to remove the `Widget` from the `WidgetTree` manually,  `flutter` will do that for you as long as the data provided updates to reflect the change. In order words, remove the item from the `List` on checkbox press and call `setState()` the application should re-render with the change. Do let me know if this helps so I can update the answer to help others.

Comment: This is basically what needed to be done the new issue is that because the list seems to have a different index it won't let me reorder it now I will be attempting to debug it and try to find a solution today

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely help you.

> replace the build method body with this

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("To-Do"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: ReorderableListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          var item = checkboxes.removeAt(oldIndex);
          checkboxes.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
      itemCount: checkboxes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Checkboxstate box = checkboxes.elementAt(index);
        return buildBox(box, index);
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

**and**

> Replace this method also

```
Card buildBox(Checkboxstate checkbox, int index) {
return Card(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    title: Text(checkbox.title),
    key: UniqueKey(),
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
    value: checkbox.value,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        checkboxes.removeAt(index);
        checkbox.value = value;
      });
    },
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: I followed these steps, and first off, I want to say thank you as initially I didn't use the item builders and found that they are extremely useful. I now have a new issue, the checklist items are unable to move. I believe it has something to do with the fact that itembuilder has a different index since this index is changing anytime I move the list and all of my attempts to fix it only made it worse

Comment: How do you want to move the items? I mean what is actual scenario to develop, please explain or show me graphically if you have something

Comment: it will be like the reorderable widget for now or in other words you long-press the item and it becomes draggable up or down